# integrating a join zoom button in my android application

Tags: java, android

I want to create a button in my android application that when it's clicked should open the zoom app that is installed on the phone and join a particular meeting that I have created. can someone help me with this?

I'm new to this so I have very little idea of how to do this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thank you for your replay. but i somehow managed to do it.